# MetaPost not working

Tags: miktex, metapost

The recent update seems to have broken metapost. Anyone else having problems? The following is a MWE taken from the document that used to compile. Thanks for any help.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[reqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fourier}
%% use option 'nowrite' if graphics are stable
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}
\usempxclass{article}
\usempxpackage{amsmath}
\usempxpackage{fourier}
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%% PROBLEM 1a
\begin{mpost}[name=1a]
numeric v, u, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;
numeric ix, iy, tx, ty;
numeric ahlen, ahpos;
numeric gridwidth, axeswidth;
picture xl[], yl[];
ix=1; iy=1;
tx=1; ty=1;
v=0.8725cm;
u:=(1/tx)*v;
xmin=tx*(-6)/ix; xmax=tx*(6)/ix;
ymin=ty*(-6)/iy; ymax=ty*(6)/iy;
gridwidth:=0.46; axeswidth:=4*gridwidth;
ahlen:=((4/72.27)*2.54*tx);
% default arrowhead length is 4pt, compensate for scaling by $tx
ahangle:=36;
% metapost default arrowhead angle is 45 degrees
ahpos:=1;
labeloffset:=3.125;
%%%% Draw the axes
pickup pencircle scaled (gridwidth*1.0pt);
for i=xmin upto xmax: draw (i,ymin)*u--(i,ymax)*u; endfor;
for i=ymin upto ymax: draw (xmin,i)*u--(xmax,i)*u; endfor;

def opencircle(expr z, d, rgb) =
 begingroup%
 save p;
 path p; background=white;
 p = fullcircle scaled (2.3333*d) shifted (z);
 fill p withcolor background;
 draw p withcolor (rgb) withpen currentpen scaled 0.5;
 endgroup%
enddef;

def solidcircle(expr z, d, rgb) =
    save p; path p;
    p = fullcircle scaled (2*d) shifted (z);
    filldraw p withcolor (rgb);
enddef;

%% Horizontal labels;
xl[0] = thelabel.bot(\btex\large $-6$ etex, (xmin + tx*0,0)*u);
  unfill bbox xl[0];
  draw xl[0];
xl[1] = thelabel.bot(\btex\large $-5$ etex, (xmin + tx*1,0)*u);
  unfill bbox xl[1];
  draw xl[1];
xl[2] = thelabel.bot(\btex\large $-4$ etex, (xmin + tx*2,0)*u);
  unfill bbox xl[2];
  draw xl[2];
xl[3] = thelabel.bot(\btex\large $-3$ etex, (xmin + tx*3,0)*u);
  unfill bbox xl[3];
  draw xl[3];
xl[4] = thelabel.bot(\btex\large $-2$ etex, (xmin + tx*4,0)*u);
  unfill bbox xl[4];
  draw xl[4];
xl[5] = thelabel.bot(\btex\large $-1$ etex, (xmin + tx*5,0)*u);
  unfill bbox xl[5];
  draw xl[5];
xl[6] = thelabel.bot(\btex\large $1$ etex, (xmin + tx*7,0)*u);
  unfill bbox xl[6];
  draw xl[6];
xl[7] = thelabel.bot(\btex\large $2$ etex, (xmin + tx*8,0)*u);
  unfill bbox xl[7];
  draw xl[7];
xl[8] = thelabel.bot(\btex\large $3$ etex, (xmin + tx*9,0)*u);
  unfill bbox xl[8];
  draw xl[8];
xl[9] = thelabel.bot(\btex\large $4$ etex, (xmin + tx*10,0)*u);
  unfill bbox xl[9];
  draw xl[9];
xl[10] = thelabel.bot(\btex\large $5$ etex, (xmin + tx*11,0)*u);
  unfill bbox xl[10];
  draw xl[10];
xl[11] = thelabel.bot(\btex\large $6$ etex, (xmin + tx*12,0)*u);
  unfill bbox xl[11];
  draw xl[11];

%% Vertical labels;
yl[0] = thelabel.lft(\btex\large $-6$ etex, (0,ymin + ty*0)*u);
  unfill bbox yl[0];
  draw yl[0];
yl[1] = thelabel.lft(\btex\large $-5$ etex, (0,ymin + ty*1)*u);
  unfill bbox yl[1];
  draw yl[1];
yl[2] = thelabel.lft(\btex\large $-4$ etex, (0,ymin + ty*2)*u);
  unfill bbox yl[2];
  draw yl[2];
yl[3] = thelabel.lft(\btex\large $-3$ etex, (0,ymin + ty*3)*u);
  unfill bbox yl[3];
  draw yl[3];
yl[4] = thelabel.lft(\btex\large $-2$ etex, (0,ymin + ty*4)*u);
  unfill bbox yl[4];
  draw yl[4];
yl[5] = thelabel.lft(\btex\large $-1$ etex, (0,ymin + ty*5)*u);
  unfill bbox yl[5];
  draw yl[5];
yl[6] = thelabel.lft(\btex\large $1$ etex, (0,ymin + ty*7)*u);
  unfill bbox yl[6];
  draw yl[6];
yl[7] = thelabel.lft(\btex\large $2$ etex, (0,ymin + ty*8)*u);
  unfill bbox yl[7];
  draw yl[7];
yl[8] = thelabel.lft(\btex\large $3$ etex, (0,ymin + ty*9)*u);
  unfill bbox yl[8];
  draw yl[8];
yl[9] = thelabel.lft(\btex\large $4$ etex, (0,ymin + ty*10)*u);
  unfill bbox yl[9];
  draw yl[9];
yl[10] = thelabel.lft(\btex\large $5$ etex, (0,ymin + ty*11)*u);
  unfill bbox yl[10];
  draw yl[10];
yl[11] = thelabel.lft(\btex\large $6$ etex, (0,ymin + ty*12)*u);
  unfill bbox yl[11];
  draw yl[11];
%%%% Place the labels
if ((xmax-xmin)*(ymax-ymin) > 99):
label.top(\btex {\Large $ x $} etex, (xmax*u+1.125*(24/64)*v,1.125(4/64)*v));
label.rt (\btex {\Large $ y $} etex, (1.125*(4/64)*v,ymax*u+1.125*(24/64)*v));
else:
label.top(\btex {\large $ x $} etex, (xmax*u+(24/64)*v,(4/64)*v));
label.rt (\btex {\large $ y $} etex, ((4/64)*v,ymax*u+(24/64)*v));
fi;
pickup pencircle scaled (axeswidth*1.0pt);
drawdblarrow (0,ymin-ahpos*ahlen)*u--(0,ymax+ahpos*ahlen)*u;
drawdblarrow (xmin-ahpos*ahlen,0)*u--(xmax+ahpos*ahlen,0)*u;

solidcircle((-5,4)*u,0.15*u,black);
solidcircle((-4,-2)*u,0.15*u,black);
solidcircle((-3,3)*u,0.15*u,black);
solidcircle((-2,-4)*u,0.15*u,black);
solidcircle((-1,2)*u,0.15*u,black);
solidcircle((2,-3)*u,0.15*u,black);
solidcircle((1,5)*u,0.15*u,black);
solidcircle((2,3)*u,0.15*u,black);
solidcircle((3,4)*u,0.15*u,black);
solidcircle((4,5)*u,0.15*u,black);

\end{mpost}

\usempost[width=3in]{1a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Imho the % after begingroup and endgroup in the opencircle definition are wrong.

Comment: Deleted. Thanks.

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: I deleted the % characters.

Answer (score 1):

The given code *never* worked: I tried it with working TeX Live distributions from 2015 to 2019, always getting the same error.

The `.mp` file that gets written out shows

```
def opencircle(expr z, d, rgb) = begingroupsave p;
 path p;
 background=white;
 p = fullcircle scaled (2.3333*d) shifted (z);
 fill p withcolor background;
 draw p withcolor (rgb) withpen currentpen scaled 0.5;
 endgroupenddef;
```

which is of course wrong. Remember that `gmp` reads the `mpost` environment with TeX conventions *on*, in order to do macro expansion. Thus the `%` symbols after `begingroup` and `endgroup` hide the endlines and the output is

```
begingroupsave
```

which is of course wrong. You can add comments to your Metapost snippets, but ensure a space precedes `%` or the comment is on a line of its own. Metapost essentially ignores line breaks, which are simply translated to spaces.

Removing the wrong `%` characters yields the expected result.

[image]

Comment: Even with removing the comment characters it's not compiling.

Comment: My apology. I thought I stated what distribution I was using: MiKTeX 2.9.7050 (64-bit).

Comment: If I take the file generated from gmp and compile it from the command line I get the following:  

   C:\Temp>mpost --interaction=errorstopmode --tex=latex mwe.mp  
   This is MetaPost, version 2.00 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit) (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)  
   (C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/mpost.mp  
   (C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/plain.mp  
   Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004) ) (./mwe.mp  
  
No output and the log file is empty. Files containing asymptote code compile properly. Only metapost seems to be affected.

Comment: You can check if your `mpost` invocation crashed by running `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` immediately afterwards. A very high (or negative value) signals an error condition (e.g., access violation). You also can check the Windows event viewer.

Comment: I get -1073741819. What next?

Comment: Seems to be a bug. See https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/322